# why does zsh `for` loop error with `command not found: filename.txt`? despite filename.txt being a parameter and not a command

Tags: shell, zsh

The following shell history shows two attempts to rename files, the second attempt worked.  But the first attempt did not and I have no idea why...

```
❯ ls
step-10.txt  step-12.txt  step-14.txt  step-16.txt  step-18.txt  step-1.txt  step-3.txt  step-5.txt  step-7.txt  step-9.txt
step-11.txt  step-13.txt  step-15.txt  step-17.txt  step-19.txt  step-2.txt  step-4.txt  step-6.txt  step-8.txt
❯ for f in *.txt; do
newname=$(echo $f | sed 's/txt/md/')\
mv $f $newname
done
zsh: command not found: step-10.txt
zsh: command not found: step-11.txt
zsh: command not found: step-12.txt
zsh: command not found: step-13.txt
zsh: command not found: step-14.txt
zsh: command not found: step-15.txt
zsh: command not found: step-16.txt
zsh: command not found: step-17.txt
zsh: command not found: step-18.txt
zsh: command not found: step-19.txt
zsh: command not found: step-1.txt
zsh: command not found: step-2.txt
zsh: command not found: step-3.txt
zsh: command not found: step-4.txt
zsh: command not found: step-5.txt
zsh: command not found: step-6.txt
zsh: command not found: step-7.txt
zsh: command not found: step-8.txt
zsh: command not found: step-9.txt
↵ Error. Exit status 127.
❯ for f in *.txt; do
mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/txt/md/')
done
❯ ls
step-10.md  step-12.md  step-14.md  step-16.md  step-18.md  step-1.md  step-3.md  step-5.md  step-7.md  step-9.md
step-11.md  step-13.md  step-15.md  step-17.md  step-19.md  step-2.md  step-4.md  step-6.md  step-8.md
```

Why does it work when I place `$(echo $f | sed 's/txt/md/')` on the line with `mv` but not when it's assigned to the variable?  Why does it say `command not found: $f` when my loop is providing `$f` as an argument to the `mv` command?

Comment: get rid of the backslash at the end of the `newname` assignment line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That backslash means it's evaluating

```
newname=$(echo $f | sed 's/txt/md/')mv $f $newname
```

which of course treats the filename as the name of a command to run (The *mv* is part of the `newname` variable)

You don't need `sed` at all here; just use parameter expansion:

```sh
for f in *.txt; do
    mv "$f" "${f/%txt/md}"
done
```

There are also several different programs named `rename` (`prename`, `rename.ul`, etc. depending on OS) that can mass rename files; check man pages for which ones (if any) you have installed and usage.

Comment: In `zsh`'s `${name/pattern/repl}` expansion, a `%` at the start of the pattern means it only matches at the end of the string. A `#` anchors to the beginning. `#%` means the pattern has to match the entire string; or use `${name:/pattern/repl}` for the same effect.

Comment: in `${name...` we're dealing with a variable like `$name`??  (shell expansion syntax often confuses me)

Comment: and in `mv "$f" "${f/%txt/md}"` the "f" in `${f/` is an f because we're dealing with a variable named `$f`?

Comment: @alec Yes. `zsh` documentation uses *name* (and sometimes *spec*) in the section on parameter expansion. It can be a plain variable name, or a string that is the result of nested expansion, etc. depending on what you're doing. In this case, the variable `f`.

Comment: Thanks.  It's great to learn about the search/replace feature of parameter expansion.